# Don't want my hard drive to die again!

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup

A couple of months ago, my Mac Book Pro wouldn't start up - it would make it halfway through and then power down. I took it to the repair store, and they said the hard drive was broken, and they needed to replace it. (Interestingly, they were able to transfer everything in my Applications/ folder to the new hard drive, and that was actually 85% of my content.)

Now, my computer is having problems booting again. Sometimes it takes a long time, sometimes it doesn't finish booting at all. I was able to boot it into safe mode, and it seems to be working alright right now. What steps should I take now to deal with this problem and not make it any worse?

Comment: The first thing I'd do is use [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) or [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731), whichever is appropriate, to thoroughly test the hardware.

Comment: @user3439894 I am in safe mode right now, and I can't even open Finder or System Preferences. Is that normal? Finder just started to open after 2 minutes.

Comment: @user3439894 ok, extended testing just finished. No problems found.

Comment: Running "Repair" in Disk Utility was also successful, but did not fix the problem.

Comment: If it works in Safe Boot, try making a new admin account & booting to that.

Comment: @Tetsujin ok, i have done so. What should i do now?

Comment: If it behaves under that account, then it is something you have installed under the other. Next is the not-too-easy process of elimination to find out what. Start with Login Items, perhaps.

Comment: @Tetsujin The thing is, I can only log into my main account or the new account in safe mode,  and both seem to run equally well in safe mode.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am booting in verbose mode now and I'm mostly getting I/O error.

Comment: I/O error would usually be a sign of a failing drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's interesting because I just got it replaced, and I have not dropped it or anything since then. Do you think I was given defective drive?

Comment: Impossible to tell.

Comment: @Tetsujin Also, why are Apple Hardware test and Disk Utility repair not reporting any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the bracket cable is broken. Nothing is wrong with the hard drive.

Comment: Buy an external hard drive for a time machine backup to be safer for the future.